# Xpath - получить несколько элементов

Tags: php, xpath

Помогите из XML выбрать только значения ftpServer и ftpDstDir . Найти все ftpServer получается, но выбрать еще и  ftpDstDir не получается.

Структура XML:

```
<ftpUpl>
<FtpUpload
    name = "sdsdl"
    ftpServer = "123456789"
    ftpServerPort = "21"
    ftpDstDir = "/123/"
    ftpActiveMode = "true"
    ftpTimeout = "10"
    ftpFileType = "binary"
    saveTime = "false"
    queueWarnOn = "20"
    queueWarnOff = "2"
/>
</ftpUpl>
```

Мой запрос, который получает все ftpServer:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/ftpUpl/FtpUpload/@ftpServer');
```

Comment: " Найти все ftpDstDir получается, но выбрать еще и ftpDstDir не получается." так вы их выбрали уже :D

Comment: Ошибся в написании. Имелось ввиду ftpServer получается.

Comment: да понял уже, а что именно не получаеться выбрать? или вы хотите одним xpath запросом вытащить всё?

Comment: Да я хочу в одном запросе получить два элемента ftpServer  и ftpDstDir

Comment: Попробуйте склеить два запроса инструкцией или `|` но не уверен прокатит или нет.

Comment: вам их парами выбрать надо? или просто список всего? или какой формат то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше выражение должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
/ftpUpl/FtpUpload/@ftpServer  | /ftpUpl/FtpUpload/@ftpDstDir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/ftpUpl/FtpUpload/@ftpServer  | /ftpUpl/FtpUpload/@ftpDstDir ');
```